# Jenkins Execute shell is failed after executing ssh to a remote server

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, ssh, stdin

I am creating a Jenkins job in which am running a `ssh` command to execute a script for comparing two folders using `diff` command on a remote server. Script is running fine, output file is getting created. But after this command Jenkins execute shell block is failed.

**Command:**

`ssh -T user@dtest.com "bash /tmp/sample.sh" >> result.txt`

**Log**:

> ssh -T user@dtest.com "bash /tmp/sample.sh" >> result.txt
>
> stdin: is not a tty
>
> "Execute shell" is marked as failure

Comment: Are you sure the script is running properly? The file will be created regardless of how the script runs because you're using the standard stream redirection operator.

Comment: What happens if you replace `-T` by `-t`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `sample.sh` is supposed to do, but I understand that you are trying to capture what is logged by this script.

I would try several solutions:

```
ssh -T user@dtest.com "bash /tmp/sample.sh >> result.txt"
```

This should save your output in your remote server. Then you could copy this file from remote to local using:

```
scp user@dtest.com:/remote/dir/result.txt /local/dir/
```

More context: [Copying files from server to local computer using ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553428/copying-files-from-server-to-local-computer-using-ssh)

If you are choosing this solution, you could also consider to write your `result.txt` directly from your script, and keep the console output for important logging purpose.

Another Solution I could think of would be to use

```
ssh user@dtest.com "bash /tmp/sample.sh" > result.txt
```

With this solution you will redirect your output directly to your local machine.
But you will need to delete the ssh "-T" option. And you will run into other problems with Jenkins. So this might not fit you.

`ssh -T` Disables pseudo-tty allocation, what sounds like your problem's root cause. (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ssh-1.html)