# How to copy file from server to local using ssh and sudo su?

Tags: ssh, copy-paste, sudo

Somewhat related to: [Copying files from server to local computer using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553428/copying-files-from-server-to-local-computer-using-ssh)

When debugging on DEV server I can see logs with

```bash
# Bash for Windows
ssh username@ip

# On server as username
sudo su

# On server as su
cat path/to/log.file
```

The problem is that while every line of the file is indeed printed out, the CLI seems to have a height limit, and I can only see the last "so many" lines after the printing is done.

If there is a better solution, please bring it forward, otherwise, how do I copy the "log.file" to my computer.

Note: I don't have a password for my username, because the user is created with `echo "$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | tee /etc/sudoers.d/$USER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `sudo su` copy the file to the `/tmp` folder on the server with

```bash
cp path/to/log.file /tmp/log.file
```

After that the standard command should work

```bash
scp username@ip:/tmp/log.file log.file
```

`log.file` is now in the current directory (`echo $PWD`).